# How would one rotate a PDF?

Tags: ipad, pdf

I have a scanned PDF document on an iPad 2 (iOS 6) that I need to rotate but cannot find any easy way to do this. How would I engage such an endeavor?

Comment: Are you transferring the PDF from a computer? If so, it might be easier to rotate it on the computer first before transferring to your iPad.

Comment: Which app are you using to view the PDF?

Comment: @patrix i've been trying many. adobe reader, kindle, and the native app (i'm not really very good at mac, but i'm trying)

Comment: You don't have to be good at using a Mac to use your iPad :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lot of PDF viewers on the iPad allow rotation of PDF files. An example would be [GoodReader](http://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/goodreader-for-ipad/id363448914?mt=8) which is a good app to have anyway if you need offline access to PDFs etc. To open a PDF in GoodReader e.g. from Mail use the "Open with..." button.

Answer (score 0):

You can download an APPLE App Store called Bluebeam Revu. I believe you will have to pay for this. Once you port your PDF over to the app, you will need to select the square icon that has 4 boxes. Your PDF will appear to the left and will be a smaller version. You then can take 2 fingers an rotate your PDF to the position you want. Then you can select the icon at the top to email it back to yourself. I select "flaten and email". This works great and is very easy. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

[PDF Splicer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-splicer-free/id496224447?mt=8) is a very good app for that. It's free.

Answer (score -3):

Use this free online website, it worked for me using one drive as a file holding medium, you could also try using google drive for this.

https://www.rotatepdf.net